# Why my app look like it's opening a new window every time I navigate on it

Tags: android, flutter, user-interface

I work on an flutter android app to apply job, and it's fine, but it look like there is an opening windows every time I click on something (see the video to understand more). Except when I use a back arrow..

I use those expression to redirect to a new screen:

Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const JobOfferHistoryScreen()));

Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/historyscreen');

But both ends up with the same result. Anyone got an idea to help me fix this?

https://gifyu.com/image/ST4gj

Comment: It looks like you run the Navigator.push... multiple times in your code. Could you provide a code sample in which can be seen how the new route gets called.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to not show the animation during navigation you can use pageRouteBuilder and set duration to 0 like

```dart
Navigator.pushReplacement(
    context, 
    PageRouteBuilder(
        pageBuilder: (context, animation1, animation2) => JobOfferHistoryScreen(),
        transitionDuration: Duration.zero,
        reverseTransitionDuration: Duration.zero,
    ),
);
```